# Cleanest way to make a proxy/passthrough for a JavaScript object that can be called from Dart

Tags: javascript, dart, dart-js-interop

This is admittedly weird, but bear with me:

I'm using Dart's js-interop package so that I can call from Dart into JavaScript.

The system I have to work with has a communication path via a particular global JavaScript object - this object is inserted into the JavaScript context as a way to call into native code, but it's not a true JavaScript object; it's a little hacky.

I can't make a Dart Proxy directly to this object because the Proxy code depends on certain constructors and aspects of the prototype chain that don't exist for this hacky object. Specifically, the JsObject_JsObject function generated by dart2js tries to  call "constr.bind.apply" where constr is the constructor of the JS object. This object doesn't have a .bind property since it doesn't inherit correctly from other stuff, and all my attempts to add/fix the prototype chain have failed so far.

If I could fix that, it'd be great. But my other option is to proxy a proxy - make a true Javascript object that wraps and proxies the wacky-hacky-native-object, then a Dart Proxy for that.

I'm curious what the cleanest way to make that JS proxy would be - I'd like to call various functions from Dart, with varying numbers of parameters, and have the calls pass through cleanly to the native object, *without* having to constantly maintain my JS proxy by making sure any functions added to the native object are added to the proxy.

Does anybody have any great/creepy ideas to make this proxy idiot-proof so that it doesn't need a lot of maintenance, but just automagically redirects calls to the native object?

Answer (score 0):

`constr.bind.apply` is only call on Js Object creation from Dart. You can simply make a JS function that creates your particular JS Object (for instance `createWtfObject()`). Once created on JS side (by calling from Dart `context.callMethod('createWtfObject')`) you should be able to use it without problem from Dart side.